# Remotely start/restart android application

Tags: android, remote-access

I have android TVBox with the Droidmote Server installed on it that let's me to control this box via phone. It works well except 1 thing, from time to time I can't connect to it and the only thing I can do is to take Infrared remote control and just open this Droidmote application manually.

I can't find the reason what is stopping it or what is the reason of that, I can't also find any logs or something like that. So, I am looking for the solution how can I do remotely either:

1. Start it by installing some other software
2. Schedule something to restart this application time to time
3. Write own application that would allow to do something to solve this problem

Any other possible options are welcome. Currently the only way I see to solve it is to use something like raspberry with IR blaster configured and then send signals emulating remote control, but it's kind of ...

UPDATED:

I tried to install Llama app and create a macro to open the application if it was closed. It didn't help...

Comment: Not an answer, but while you are waiting for one you might wish to take a look at the [automation tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) at our sister site. I'm sure some of those apps could deal with that (restart the app when it's stopped, or the like).

Comment: Download macrodroid and configured it to run that app if it was closed, let's see if it will help

Comment: Be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) when it worked out :) Apart from that: Could you please [edit] your question and state whether the app must be free (money-wise, or open-source) or how much you'd be willing to pay? Myself, I'm using *Tasker* and am quite happy with it. But that's not free but ~5 bucks. I'm pretty sure *Tasker* would fit the task (oops). Check the [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) for details, especially for where to get a free 7-day trial if you're interested.

Comment: @Izzy llama didn't help

Comment: Didn't help or didn't work? What errors did you encounter? You could ask a "How to achieve this with Llama or MacroDroid" question at Android.SE; I often see MacroDroid recommended over there.

Comment: I am not getting any errors. I do not know how to troubleshoot what exactly is going on. The DroidMote Server just stops responding after some time and I need to open this Application again. I am not even sure that it is closed and do not know where to check any kind of logs

Comment: If your TVBox offers a "running" tab in *Settings › Apps* you could (as a first step) hopefully figure if it has "quit" or is just hanging. In the latter case I don't know how any "user-tool" could detect that (except maybe by sending a "dummy command" and getting no answer). If it quit, automation apps dealing with apps could detect that by the condition "app is not running".